# Numeric Keypad not working after sign In

Tags: 12.04

I can't think of what would cause this problem. The num lock light is on and I can sign in with the number pad (password is both alpha and numeric ) but when I get into Ubuntu the number pad stops working with numlock light on or off. What could cause this and how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem once. Solve it here by

> system settings --> universal access --> pointing and clicking

Here uncheck the option "Control the pointer using Keypad"